# Normality tests in sas programming

Tags: sas

I am doing sas atm and I need to find if the total members is normally distributed by age.
Here r is total members according to each year and each age group.I need to find it if the members are normally distributed by each agegroup.

```
year    agegroup members(%)
1997    16-21   20.70
1997    22-29   46.70
1997    30-39   60.80
1997    40-49   64.20
1997    50-54   63.20
1997    55-59   57.80
1997    60-64   47.10
1997      65+   12.20
1998    16-21   18.00
1998    22-29   45.60
1998    30-39   60.20
1998    40-49   64.40
1998    50-54   63.20
1998    55-59   57.90
1998    60-64   44.70
1998      65+   12.50
1999    16-21   17.80
1999    22-29   43.40
1999    30-39   57.30
1999    40-49   62.40
1999    50-54   61.10
1999    55-59   55.10
1999    60-64   42.40
1999      65+   10.10
```

Comment: Try googling 'SAS normality test', then make an attempt at solving your problem.  If you're still stuck then post your attempt on here

Comment: PROC UNIVARIATE DATA=totalmembers normaltest; 
TITLE2 "Analysis of Age grouped by members"; 
 CLASS age; 
 VAR members; 
RUN; 
well I have tried the proc univariate process but not sure if this code is right or this is the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
proc univariate data=test;
class agegroup;
var members;
histogram / normal nochart;
run;
```

This will give you 3 normality tests, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Cramer-von Mises, and Anderson-Darling.  Try Google, Wikipedia, or the SAS documentation on each test if you are unfamiliar.

Note, your example only has 3 observations for each group.  Any test is going to have a very low power with that sample size.

Comment: Thanks Dom,Is there any way I could show year by year affect,as I need the chart it shows the effect in the chart but How could I show the reference in the code? I was thinking may be put weight as year?